# Webpack not loading correct module

Tags: cordova, webpack

I have a Cordova app which I'm building for both iOS and Android. I've just switched to the WKWevView engine, and it's now mostly working, but I get the following error when using the js-image npm module:

> TypeError: IOBuffer is not a constructor

I'm stuck on how to diagnose this further. I suspect it might be a problem with Webpack, and maybe nothing at all to do with WKWebView. Webpack produces this code:

```
const IOBuffer = __webpack_require__(102);
var io = new IOBuffer();
```

And it's here that the error is thrown. I inspected the IOBuffer object, and it's just an empty hash ({}).

Any suggestions on how I can diagnose this? Why would Webpack not load the correct class?

The iobuffer module is installed as several versions:

```
quasar-app@0.0.1 /Users/kristiankauper/dev/hileadzz_app
├─┬ image-js@0.21.6
│ ├─┬ fast-bmp@1.0.0
│ │ └── iobuffer@3.2.0 
│ ├─┬ fast-jpeg@1.0.1
│ │ ├── iobuffer@2.1.0 
│ │ └─┬ tiff@2.1.0
│ │   └── iobuffer@2.1.0  deduped
│ ├─┬ fast-png@3.1.3
│ │ └── iobuffer@4.0.1  deduped
│ └─┬ tiff@3.0.1
│   └── iobuffer@4.0.1  deduped
└── iobuffer@4.0.1
```

The error occurs when trying to load a JPEG file, so the iobuffer@2.1.0 library is being used, but it should be ok that this is an old version? I think npm and webpack keep these versions separate, right? (I can't upgrade the version because that is what the latest version of image-js/fast-jpeg requires.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that these were the problem:

```
│ ├─┬ fast-png@3.1.3
│ │ └── iobuffer@4.0.1  deduped
│ └─┬ tiff@3.0.1
│   └── iobuffer@4.0.1  deduped
```

Although these versions of fast-png and tiff both allow iobuffer@4.0.1 as a dependency, they don't appear to work with that version. I downgraded these both to the ones that require iobuffer@3.2.0, and now everything works fine:

```
├─┬ fast-png@3.1.0
│ └── iobuffer@3.2.0 
└─┬ tiff@3.0.0
  └── iobuffer@3.2.0  deduped
```